# worker thread being blocked in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I know  netty uses the Reactor pattern **to avoid creating a thread  for each  connection**, 
the core concept about this pattern is a "selector" or `epoll` system call in Linux.

But I also heard about that if a handler never close it's channel, it will occupy one worker thread and block it: doesn't that mean each connetion will use (block) one thread,so **for each accepted socket we still need to create a thread ?**

for example ,if I write a server with 10,000 persistent connections,does this server need 10,000 worker threads??

The contradiction between those two things above confused me ,can anyone explain me if I understand it wrong? thank you~

========================================

an example (with only 1 worker thread ) which can always process one client's event in the same time.

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.*;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory;
public class Netty_test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChannelFactory factory =new     NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);
        ChannelPipelineFactory cpf=new ChannelPipelineFactory(){
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
                return Channels.pipeline(new testHandler());
            }
        };
        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(cpf);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);      
        bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(100));
    }
}
class testHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
@Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {    
        System.out.println("messageReceived, handler work.");
        e.getChannel().write(e.getMessage());
        ctx.sendUpstream(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your 10,000 connections will share the worker threads. One worker thread will handle multiple connections/channels. This is why it is very important not to block the worker threads.

Comment: But in my example above,server can only handle one persistent connection .

Comment: I have tried this example both in Win7 and Linux(CentOS 5) with netty-3.2.4.Final.jar.

Comment: You have more workers than threads. Change your factory to be with 1 worker and you will see that it can handle multiple connections.

Comment: Like this: `NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1), 1);`

Answer (score 1):

1) In reactor pattern, the dispatcher get one event by listening to a list of event queues and passing the event to concrete event handler. The event handler can be executing by only one thread, thread pools or per event per thread. depends on your implementation.

2) You can add timeout timer per channel, and reset this timer on incoming data. If the timer timeout, then close this channel to prevent too many idle channels.

my 0.2 cents?

Comment: so how can my server serve two connections simultaneously by one thread??  It seems not working unless I close one channel of them.

Comment: Netty framework should support the non-blocking IO mode, serving many connection concurrently by threading pool. here is link to describe this feature http://www.slideshare.net/zaubersoftware/non-blocking-io-with-netty