# Worker threads in netty 4

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I am writing a server in which I want to process the messages from clients in separate worker threads.

In my channelRead0() of inbound handler I get the message, and I want to process the message with a worker thread (my handleWebSocketFrame has to be executed in a worker thread.) . Can anybody tell me how to do it?

```
public class WebSocketSslServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object>
{
    ....

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception
    {
        if (msg instanceof WebSocketFrame)
        {
            handleWebSocketFrame(ctx, (WebSocketFrame) msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, the "channelRead0()" method is already executed using a worker thread by Netty. You can tune Netty itself to set the amount of worker threads available, see comments in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14976589/3080094).

Comment: Glad to help but please verify it works as expected, and if it does, maybe describe the solution in an answer to your own question so others can get the same insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As vanOekel said, the "channelRead0()" method is already executed using a worker thread by Netty. 
Since I wanted to run some heavy operation on each client message I can use Java's built in thread pooling technique with in the channelRead0().

I am also incorporating johnstlr's idea of passing a reference of the thread pool to ChannelInitializer used by ServerBootstrap. This can then pass it to WebSocketSslServerHandler  in its constructor.

```
public class WebSocketSslServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object>
{
     ExecutorService cachedPool;

     public WebSocketSslServerHandler (ExecutorService pool)
     {
         this.cachedPool = pool;
     }

     @Override
     public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception
     {
         if (msg instanceof WebSocketFrame)
         {
              cachedPool.submit(new MessageHandler(ctx, (WebSocketFrame) msg));
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's intentional but that code will create a new thread pool for every instance of WebSocketFrame. You want to create the threadpool once when the application starts and submit tasks to the same instance.

Comment: as @johnstlr pointed out or you could add ```EventExecutorGroup``` to your handler (check the doc at http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html ) and then call ```ctx.executor().submit(new MessageHandler(ctx, (WebSocketFrame) msg));```

Comment: Thanks johnstlr and jknair. But I couldn't find how to attach the cached thread pool to my handler. I found how it is done for client side, but not for server side. Could you help me?

Comment: Assuming you create an instance of your server side handler for each connection, you need to pass a reference to the thread pool to the ChannelInitializer used by your ServerBootstrap. This can then pass it to your handler in its constructor (or by some other means). If your handler is shared for all connections you need to pass the thread pool to the handler when you create it. I'm not sure if the same applies to jknair's suggestion as I'm still on Netty 3.